# Input array of objects as input and return an array as output from Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have a requirement where I need to pass the nested array of objects as an input to stored procedure , get the data from table as group of different date ranges, and return all the date ranges data as an output. I am a newbie in PL/Sql , so request your guidance here .

I have gone through many articles on achieving this but I have got only the basic idea of the stored procedures and pl/sql , but I am unavailable to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

Create a collection to input:

```sql
CREATE TYPE intlist AS TABLE OF int;
```

Create a collection to output:

```sql
CREATE TYPE daterange AS OBJECT(
  start_date DATE,
  end_date   DATE
);
/
CREATE TYPE daterangelist AS TABLE OF daterange;
```

Create some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, start_date, end_date ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2019-01-02', DATE '2019-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2019-01-03', DATE '2019-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE '2019-01-04', DATE '2019-01-05' FROM DUAL;
```

**Procedure**:

Simple procedure that select from the `test_data` table and will collect date ranges into the output parameter where the row has an `id` that is a `MEMBER OF` the input array.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc (
  i_ints  IN  intlist,
  o_dates OUT daterangelist
)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT daterange( start_date, end_date )
  BULK COLLECT INTO o_dates
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  id MEMBER OF i_ints;
END;
/
```

**Testing**:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_ranges daterangelist;
BEGIN
  test_proc( intlist( 1, 3, 4 ), p_ranges );
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_ranges.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_ranges(i).start_date || ' - ' || p_ranges(i).end_date );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 01-JAN-19 - 02-JAN-19
> 03-JAN-19 - 04-JAN-19
> 04-JAN-19 - 05-JAN-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb4ef3a39ef4bca675d7845df4d91cfd)*